# Loop PHP check until text within webpage has been found

Tags: php, file, loops, while-loop, find

On pressing the submit button, I want the PHP code to check to see if a string exists within a webpage on another website.

```
$random = rand(100,1000);
strpos(file_get_contents('website.com/url.php?username='.$username), $random);
```

So, until the code has managed to find the value of $random, it won't continue with the rest of the script. The updates can take about 10 seconds.

I have tried a while script:

```
$random = rand(100,1000);
echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">'.$random.'</div>';
$key = false;

while($key){    
if(strpos(file_get_contents('website.com/url.php?username='.$username), $random)) $key = true;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://website.com` that needs to be a full http call.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just quickly changed the URL for publishing. :)

Comment: So... what's your problem? php goes in timeout? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: You might wanna sleep() for a second or two between those http requests.

Comment: @Ulver That's what the natural flow of the execution does, so it's redundant!!

Comment: I want the PHP script to continue checking until it finds the string on the remote webpage. When it finds it, then continue with the rest of the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On pressing the submit button, I want the PHP code to check to see if a string exists within a webpage on another website.

If I understood your question correctly, try this:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if(str_replace($string, "", $content) != $content)
    echo "found";
```

EDIT:

```
do {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
} while(strpos($content, $string) === false);
```

EDIT 2:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $i++;
} while(strpos($content, $string) === false && $i <= 100);
```

EDIT 3:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $i++;
} while(strpos($content, $string) === false && $i <= 100);

if($i > 100){
    echo "nothing found";
}
```

EDIT 4:

```
$startTime = time();
do {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
} while(strpos($content, $string) === false && time() - $startTime < 30);

if(time() - $startTime > 30){
    echo "nothing found";
}
```